# Testing Angular 1.3 Directive with transclution

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am having a hard time testing my own VirtualRepeatContainer Wrapper directive. The test fails at compiling my element in the following test. I am currently thinking that it might be because of missing $provide variables or because of the selfmade transclude. Let me know it that is something that has crossed your path as well

```
fdescribe('Virtual Repeat component', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module(directive.name);
    angular.mock.module('ng');
});

let $rootScope;
let $compile;
let $httpBackend;
let $scope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_) => {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/pageable/').respond(200, {
        content: [
            { item: 0 },
            { item: 1 }
        ]
    });
}));

describe('DOM Manipulation', () => {

    it('adds the virtual repeat element', () => {
        // given
    let element = angular.element('<virtual-repeat service-url="/pageable/" on-item-select="logItem(item);" search-text="none" ><div class="testing"></div></virtual-repeat>');
        $compile(element)($scope);
        console.log(element)

        // when
        $scope.$digest();

        // then
        expect(exists(element, '.virtual-repeat-container')).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

I have a virtual repeat component:

```
angular.module('virtualRepeatComponent', [])
.controller('virtualRepeatController', Controller)
.component('virtualRepeat', Component)
.directive('virtualRepeatTransclude', {
    require: '^virtualRepeat',
    link: ($scope, $element, $attrs, virtualRepeatController) => {
        virtualRepeatController.$transclude($scope, (clone) => {
            $element.empty();
            $element.append(clone);
        });
    }
});
```

part of the Controller:

```
constructor($scope, $http, $transclude) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$transclude = $transclude;
    this.$http = $http;
    this.currentPageNr = 0;
    this.hasMorePages = true;
    this.totalElements = 0;
    this.elements = [];
    this.getElements(0).then((res) => {
        this.loadingResults = false;
        this.processData(res);
    });
}
```

HTML template:

```
<div class="virtual-repeat ">
<!-- some other stuff -->
<md-virtual-repeat-container class="my-virtual-repeat-container" >
    <md-list-item
            md-virtual-repeat="item in $ctrl"
            md-on-demand
            class="repeated-item md-2-line list-item">
        <div virtual-repeat-transclude flex></div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
```

I do need to provide a new transclude due to transclude being used in the md-virtual repeat container itself.

The jasmin error messages are not really easy to decipher, any help is appreciated:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object (line 1895)
    assertArg
    assertArgFn
    annotate
    $$annotate
    injectionArgs
    invoke
    forEach
    invoke
    enforcedReturnValue
    invoke
    getService
    addDirective
    collectDirectives
    compileNodes
    compileNodes
    compileNodes
    compileNodes
    compileNodes
    compile
```